# How to return value from query?

Tags: ajax, parse-platform, return-value

i need to use the results of this query:

```
var Back = Parse.Object.extend("Back");
var query = new Parse.Query(Back);
var LastSerialNumber;

    query.get("ghxbtU2KSl", {
        success: function(result){
            LastSerialNumber=result.get("SerialNumber");
            return LastSerialNumber;

        }
    });

alert(LastSerialNumber);
```

This code doesn't work correctly (it alerts undefined). Why? How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `query.get()` method is asynchronous. That means that your method will exit before the `success` function gets called. Try this instead:

```
console.log("start of function");

var query = new Parse.Query('Back')
query.get("ghxbtU2KSl", {
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("start of callback");

        var lsn = result.get("SerialNumber");
        alert(lsn);

        console.log("end of callback");
    }
});

console.log("end of function");
```

The log statements will help you see the asynchronous call.